# Remove Minus signs in XML inside a tag

Tags: php

I'm trying to use preg_replace to replace - to _ between Tags only

Test string normaly received in the header response of a POST request

```
  $response['body'] = <<<STR
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <tracking-events>
        <tracking-event>
        <type>DELIVERED</type>
        <time>2012-12-04T11:45:08.554+0200</time>
        <tracking-id>AB10000</tracking-id>
        </tracking-event>
        </tracking-events>
    STR;
```

Can you help me out changing - to _ and keep the date format as is

```
$response['body'] = <<<STR
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <tracking_events>
    <tracking_event>
    <type>DELIVERED</type>
    <time>2012-12-04T11:45:08.554+0200</time>
    <tracking_id>AB10000</tracking_id>
    </tracking_event>
    </tracking_events>
STR;
```

Comment: 1st mistake: using regular expressions on html/xml. 2nd mistake: not using DOM. 3rd mistake: not actually asking a question

Comment: Do you want to change the name of nodes on any arbitrary XML string or only in the format you show?

Comment: The xml is a response. in this format. I use SimpleXMLElement for extracting the children and value as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and it worked! :D

```
 $xml=preg_replace('/<([^>]*?)-([^>]*?)>/', '<$1_$2>',$xml);
```

Comment: Works, but in case <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> is set, uft_8 is the result :(

Comment: $response['body'] = preg_replace('/(<[^>?]*?)-/', '$1_', $response['body']); does the trick

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a XSL-stylesheet to transform the Document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="*"> 
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(name(), '-')">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(name(),'-','_')}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet will create a new element with the fixed nodeName and copies the attributes and childNodes onto that node, that's all.

Demo: [**http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/5Wuq6P**](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/5Wuq6P)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using regular expression? Something like

```
$response['body'] = preg_replace('(<[^>]*)[a-zA-Z]\-[a-zA-Z]([^>]*)', '$1_$2', $response['body']);
```

Not tested the above, but I think it should work.

Comment: Could be dangerous, if any of the XML nodes contain arbitrary text.

Comment: the `-` doesn't need to be escaped if it isn't between `[]`, also `[^>]` includes `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: $response['body'] = preg_replace('/(<[^>]*)\-([^>]*)/i', '$1_$2', $response['body']); works, but if UFT-8 is mentioned it screwed up

Answer (score 0):

This loops through the XML representation. I'm afraid any attributes will be lost (it should be easy enough to tweak the function to retain them if necessary). It's a generic function which won't be tripped up by text content.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');


$response['body'] = <<<STR
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <tracking-events>
    <tracking-event>
    <type>DELIVERED</type>
    <time>2012-12-04T11:45:08.554+0200</time>
    <tracking-id>AB10000</tracking-id>
    </tracking-event>
    </tracking-events>
STR;

$existing = new SimpleXMLElement($response['body']);
$name = $existing->getName();
$name = str_replace('-', '_', $name);
$new = new SimpleXMLElement('<' . $name . '/>');

add_corrected_nodes($existing, $new);

function add_corrected_nodes(&$from, &$to) {
    foreach ($from as $k => $v) {
        $new = str_replace('-', '_', $k);
        $child = $to->addChild($new);
        if ($from->$k->children()) {
            add_corrected_nodes($from->$k->children(), $child);
        } else {
            $to->$new = $v;
        }
    }
}

print_r($new->asXML());
```